# Cómo subir array de imágenes a MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de crear un array con las rutas de mis imagenes seleccionadas para poder insertar las en un campo de mi BD mysql, sin embargo al realizar el insert solo se agreaga la primera ruta creada, les comparto mi codigo.

Ayuda!

```
$dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino

$ruta=array($target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename); //Indicamos la ruta de destino, así como el nombre del archivo

$b=implode($ruta);
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Veo el array... ¿Y dónde lo usas en el insert? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.